# Targeting different versions of Outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I have a program that has the ability to send out emails generated progmatically.

Most of the office (including me) have Outlook 2010 installed, but due to upgrades there are a handful of people with Outlook 2013, and one with Outlook 2016.

I'd like to be able to have the program work no matter which version of Outlook is installed, since there are no plans to upgrade the rest of the office for a while.

**Edit:** My current method

Refferences: C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Private Sub cmdEmailInvite_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdEmailInvite.Click
    If lstInvites.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim Subject As String = "Invite Code"
        Dim Body As String = "Please visit our registration page"

        Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
        Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem

        oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        oEmail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
        oEmail.To = lstInvites.SelectedItems(0).Text
        oEmail.Subject = Subject
        oEmail.Body = Body
        oEmail.Display()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `I'd like to be able to have the program work no matter which version of Outlook` How can we help if we don't know how you are doing it now? There are ***differences*** you know across versions and not one is the same. Either way you will end up writing much more because of this...

Comment: @Codexer Good point. Current code added.

Comment: The `dll` you are using is correct for 2013 and 2016, not for 2010. I am afraid though you can't reference 2 different versions of the interop.

Comment: One option is to create a seperate `dll`, determine what version is installed on the pc and use either one depending upon the version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out [NetOffice](https://netoffice.codeplex.com/), which supports working with multiple versions of Office.  There is an example of sending email with Outlook [on the web site](https://netoffice.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Outlook_Example03_VB).  I have not used the Outlook API, but the Word API has worked well for me, and they are (I believe) pretty much the same as the regular automation APIs.

Comment: This is looking real promising

Answer (score 0):

I always use [System.Net.Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx). You just need to know the Mail Server's location.
Here is also a good resource [www.systemnetmail.com](http://www.systemnetmail.com/)

Comment: This assembly sends emails directly using SMTP. The question was about sending via MS Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you include the interop dll along with your app and target the lowest supported version of Outlook (2010), you will be fine.
You also need to make sure that he "Specific Version" on the reference is set to false.